# Was wondering if it was possible to change the order in which results are printed out in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Right now it gives me results of all the queries in order, but what if I want the results to only print the most recent query? Or go in reverse order by print the most recent query then the one before and the one before and so on?

Have been looking through the options and can't really find an option for it

Comment: SSMS is really the development and debugging tool. Once presentation concerns start to take over, it's time to build an actual application front end or find an actual *presentation* oriented tool (for example, a report builder) for consuming the results.

Comment: The answer is "no" anyway. SSMS will just return every resultset in the order it is received. The only config option is "discard results after execution" and this will display no results at all